# In JavaScript, what's the difference between myArray.length = 0 vs myArray = new Array()?

Tags: javascript

Regarding JavaScript, when clearing an array, I've found two methods:

```
myArray.length = 0;
```

vs

```
myArray = new Array()
```

I would guess `myArray.length = 0;` keeps the reference while `myArray = newArray()` creates a new reference making previous references void.

What's the difference (if any) between the two methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct this time. `new Array()` creates a new instance of array and assign it to `myArray`.
`myArray.length = 0` empties an old array while myArray still points to the old array.

Btw, it is better to use `[]` notation than `new Array()`.

I personally always try to use `myArray.length = 0;` since it actually empties the content of the array.

Comment: Nice to see different approaches. Why it is better to use `[]` notation than `new Array()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.length = 0; // Signifies empty array
[1,2,3] // Length of this array is 3
```

So basically, an array with content is overwritten with an empty array.

You can also use this:

```
myarray = []; //More simple and elegant!!!
```

Performance wise: `[]` is faster than `new Array();`

As juno already said: `new Array()` creates a new instance of the array (this array will be of the size mentioned in arguments) and assigns it to myArray.